# factor to DateTime giving NA's

Tags: r, data-science

I read the data from the text file using `read.table("url",..)` using R . In text file the their are variable with Date and time but the class of those variable is factor. Now i need to convert that to the DateTime class .I used lot of ways but when ever i do i can see all data of those variable is NA.

```
mydata <- read.table("C:/household_power_consumption.txt", header=TRUE, sep=";", na.strings="?" )

mydata$Date<-strptime(x=as.character(mydata$Date),format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")

sub1<-subset(mydata,mydata$Date>=as.POSIXct("01/02/2006") & mydata$Date<=as.POSIXct("02/02/2006"))
```

This is some of the sample data

```
Date             Time      D1     D2        D3      
16/12/2006      17:26:00  5.374   0.498   233.290
16/12/2006     17:27:00   5.388   0.502   233.740  
16/12/2007     17:28:00   3.666   0.528   235.680
```

need to get the data between the dates from 16/12/2006 to 16/12/2007

Comment: By adding argument `stringsAsFactors=F` to your `read.table()`, you won't need the `as.character()` later on. Now for the main issue, can you provide a sample of what your data looks like in the `.txt` file?

Comment: `as.POSIXct("01/02/2006")` is a problem. You can not convert date time of that format to `POSIXct` class. `as.Date("2006-01-02")` should work.

Comment: @Psidom - sure you can - `as.POSIXct("01/02/2006", format="%d/%m/%Y")`

Comment: @thelatemail Yeah. that will work. I mean without formatting, and since he is just trying to get a date point, there is no need to make it complicated.

Comment: @Psidom - true that. :-)

Comment: Thank you @Psidom and i worked as you suggested but nothing worked . I added the sample data to my post ,please look it to it .

Comment: It looks like your dates and times are in separate columns, if so the `format` in your second line should just be `"%d/%m/%Y"` (get rid of the hours and minutes parts).

Comment: I tried doing this as.Date("2006-01-02") , then it gives error like  In Ops.factor(mydata$Date, "01/02/2007") :
  ‘>=’ not meaningful for factors and again i tried to use this       mydata$Date <-as.POSIXct("01/02/2006", format="%d/%m/%Y")  , now all my Date coulmn data is chainging to "NA"

Comment: Did you follow @DominicComtois suggestion to add `stringsAsFactors=F` to your `read.table` call? That should eliminate those factor errors. Your command `mydata$Date <-as.POSIXct("01/02/2006", format="%d/%m/%Y")` is assigning a new value to a column of class `factor`, which would result in what you're describing.

Comment: yes @rasscova i did do it i don't know why but if i try to manipulate the date column all the values of that coulmn are becoming NA

Comment: It certainly seems like `mydata$Date` is still a factor column. Can you double check with `class(mydata$Date)`?

Comment: after using **as.Date(mydata$Date, format = "%m/%d/%y") ** it class is **character** @rosscova

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116536/discussion-between-sumanth-sharma-and-rosscova).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
finalData <- mydata[mydata$Date %in% c("1/2/2007","2/2/2007"),]

SetTime <-strptime(paste(finalData$Date, finalData$Time, sep=" "),"%d/%m/%Y    %H:%M:%S")

finalData <- cbind(SetTime, finalData)
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you managed to get things working the way you wanted. It should be noted though that by searching for character strings rather than dates, it's much more difficult to filter by any date range larger than 2 days (eg: the case outlined in the original question).

It should also be noted that the OP sent me the complete data file, and this code works perfectly for me, but not for them (we're both on R 3.3.0):

```
mydata <- read.table("household_power_consumption.txt", header=TRUE, sep=";", na.strings="?", stringsAsFactors=F )
mydata$Date<-as.Date( mydata$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y" )
sub1<-subset(mydata,mydata$Date>=as.Date("2007-02-01") & mydata$Date<=as.Date("2007-02-02"))
```

That last line can then easily be changed to match the date range you're after:

```
sub1<-subset(mydata,mydata$Date>=as.Date("2006-12-16") & mydata$Date<=as.Date("2007-12-16"))
```

Also just as an aside, `fread` from `data.table` speeds up the read time by an order of magnitude, and eliminated the need for `stringsAsFactors=F`:

```
library( data.table )
mydata <- fread( "household_power_consumption.txt" )
```